# PDO functions are not working in linux server

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, pdo

I decided to migrate my Web App to a Linux Server some days ago. I build it up using **`PDO (PHP)`**. In my localhost **(Windows)** te App is running perfect, but when I upload to a **Linux** server (I don't know if the OS has a influence) the PDO functions are not working.

I activated already in the *php.ini* of the Web Server the PDO Object for **Postgresql** (is the DB that I am using). The main page of the system (index.php) is correct loaded, but not one functionality is working. I tested and the system is going till the calling of the function with the PDO code, but is like the PDO functions are not working, or like if the Web Server ignore completely the PDO functions. I don't get any report or error from the server in relation with this problem.

Maybe is somebody with the experience in the case to help me?

Thx very much

Comment: After you enabled the PDO extension did you restart the web server? Have you checked the error logs for any messages?

Comment: yes, I restart the server after enable the PDO extension.

Comment: "Not working" is not really helpful in diagnostics. What are the exact error messages you get?

Comment: Hi @GeraldSchneider this is the problem for me, I don't get any error log from any sorce (neither the server or the App code)

Comment: Then add error reporting to your scripts.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 'on')` to your script

Comment: Maybe I don't get correct how the error_reporting() is working, but I just get a 500 GET Internal Server Error in the Console from the Browser. I am using: error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 'ON'); in the top of my main page. Well, at least now I received a "Internal Server error" :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can just do `phpinfo();` to find out what modules are installed.
Or from the commandline:

```
php -m
```

Additionally you could use: [class_exists('PDO')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) to find out whether the PDO class indeed is accessible.

Comment: Hi AnkiiG thx for your answer. I tried also this option like you suggested and definitly the PDO class is activeted, that means the PDO module was correct installed in the server. I don't understand where can be the problem